# Where to put the custom error page on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml, google-cloud-platform

I would like to add a custom error page on my GAE service.

From the [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses) , it doesn't mention where to put the error page.

Here is my `app.yaml` file:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
  script: mega_jav.wsgi.application

error_handlers:
- file: error_default.html

- error_code: over_quota
  file: error_over_quota.html
```

And I put my both `error_default.html` and `error_over_quota.html` in my templates folder.

It doesn't work.

Where should I put the error page into?
or can I modify the `app.yaml` file to make it works?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The templates are found in the the templates folder by the template loader, configured to do so. Assuming `templates` is in the same dir as the `app.yaml` file I'd try `templates/error_default.html` (and maybe `/templates/error_default.html` as well?)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you read the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses

It's pretty clear, the error handler referers to a file but not a static resource (in fact there is an explicit warning to not make the file overlap with the static handlers (I raised the issue with the docs in 2010 as it didn't note this fact, causing deployment problems - https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3759)

> Warning: Make sure that the path to the error response file does not
>   overlap with static file handler paths.

The page for the error handler is deployed in your code base.

And it has nothing to do with templates. Though it's path could be in your templates. However its is purely static html/text that is served if there is an uncaught error, putting it in your templates could be a source of confusion as it's not a template.

The simplest place in is the root of your project.  The file directive is a relative path not a handler